# ng directives for adding new row once using angular js

Tags: angularjs-directive

I have table of textboxes. When i try to add the text ion last row I should get new blank row of textboxes added on new row. Currently `ng-Blur` is there. And I am getting new blank row added on lost focus. But i want it on 1st key press.

If I use `ng-keypress` or `ng-change` then on entering each new character new row is added which is not right. Or can I restrict the event to once.

Please let me know what can be done?

following is my HTML code

```
<div class="col-md-5">
    <input placeholder="New Key" ng-model="propertyKey" ng-blur="addNewRow()" class="form-control" type="text" id="key">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to pass the current row index into your `ng-keypress` handler and only add a new row if the index is exactly one less than the row count.

So your component/directive template would look something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="row in $ctrl.rows">
  <input placeholder="{{ row.id }}" ng-keypress="$ctrl.handleKeypress($index)" />
</div>
```

where you pass the `$index` of the `ng-repeat` instance to your keypress handler, and that handler would look something like this (assuming `this.rows` is your data array):

```
this.handleKeypress = (rowIndex) => {
  if (rowIndex === this.rows.length - 1) {
    this.rows.push({ id: `row${rowIndex+1}` });
  }
};
```

So once you've added one extra row beyond the current one you're in, no more will be added.

Here's a plunk showing this approach:

http://plnkr.co/edit/4HbYg4S7M67Vpib6dI0E?p=preview